# Adding a Subview to parentView

Tags: objective-c, subview

I'm currently trying add a subview to the main view on button press, but having a rough time.

My code is as follows:

```
+ (CGRect) _randomFrame
{
  CGFloat x = arc4random() % 220;
  CGFloat y = (arc4random() % 200) + 100;
  return CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100);
}

+ (UIView*) _factoryUIView
{
  CGRect randomFrame = [[self class] _randomFrame];
  UIView *aView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:randomFrame] autorelease];
  aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  return aView;
}
```

My main trouble is trying to access this code from a different .m file where the button is referenced.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What is the trouble you're having accessing this code from another .m file?

Comment: You should post the code from where you are calling your `factoryUIView` from.

Answer (score 0):

Should just be a matter of calling:

```
[MainView addSubView:[Class factoryView]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the header to the class in which you are trying to use the code? or maybe you are creating a view using the factoryView method but you are not saving this view in any variable?? you should try to give us more info about your problem so we can help you.